# I can not connect to ssh through the key, what's wrong?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh

Ubuntu 16.04, I am trying to configure the connection via ssh key. Prior to this, I configured it on 18.04 with the same parameters without problems (it works). Saved the keys in /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys. When connecting to the server logs, the error is:
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory / home / user

**Folder and file permissions:**

```
600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
700 /home/user/.ssh/
755 / home / user /
Owner everywhere user: user
```

**What changed in the sshd_config config:**

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try to create new key.

Comment: Try to connect using `ssh -vvv user@host` and [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: "When connecting to the server logs," I don't understand that